# WCF post data converting to raw html instead of Json format

Tags: json, wcf, dynatree

Very new to WCF and almost got everything working except the post from JQuery to WCF.

The Jquery is processing a DynaTree and post the data the WCF service.
So far so good.

When I debug, I find that the posted data accepted as Stream inside the WCF routine is in raw format and contains HTML characters %...

I was expecting the post to send the data in Json format, but its not clear where the problem is. 
Infact, I had to comment out the content-type in the Post action as it will produce an error stating that a RAW format is expected.

The WCR URL request is somehting like localhost/TS.svc/SaveTree/New?username=thisuser

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "SaveTree/New",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]

    public List<TreeNode> SaveTree(Stream data)
    {
        string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"] ?? string.Empty; 

        var jsonString = new StreamReader(data).ReadToEnd(); 

...}
```

JQuery side:

```
onDrop: function(node, sourceNode, hitMode, ui, draggable) {

            sourceNode.move(node, hitMode);

            var dict = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();

            var postData = JSON.stringify(dict); 
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "TS.svc/SaveUserTree/New?userame=" + $("#hdnUserFile").val(),

                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                data: {tree:postData},
```

Please help. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

As you have removed the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`, your content type is now `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

So, what you see is the URL encoded JSON. To decode it to actual JSON you can use:

```
var decodedJSON = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(jsonString);
```

Comment: The line of code is very helpful. Thank you. There is one thing that I did on the Jquery side that also helped even without using this solution. Only problem is that I have no idea how it works.  In the post action of Dynatree, I was passing in data: {tree:postData} , and as work around I simply tried to pass in data: postData and then it just started working fine. As safe bet, I will keep the line of code you provided - just incase. Thanks again.

Comment: The JSON will be url encoded only if it needs to be. For example, if it contains `space` it is encoded to `+`, `&` is encoded to `%26` etc. If the JSON does not contain any characters which are considered special in a url, then encoded JSON will be same as orifinal JSON, in which case it will seem to work without decoding. If you are sending url encoded data from ajax, it will be good to keep the decoding line of code anyway.